# Stop hovering over input label from activing the input's hover styles when for...id is provided

Tags: html, css, hover, wai-aria

I'm not sure if all browsers do this but if I provide a `for` attribute on a label that corresponds to an input's `id`, this makes hovering over the label trigger the input's hover styles which is undesirable in my case. Is there any way to stop this behavior while still having a form accessible to screen readers?

```css
.field label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}
.field input {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 0.7em
}
.field input:hover {
  background: #efefff;
  border-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="myInput">Hover over this label:</label>
  <input id="myInput" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `pointer-events:none;` to disable hover effect for any element.

```css
.field label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  pointer-events:none;

}
.field input {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 0.7em
}
.field input:hover {
  background: #efefff;
  border-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label for="myInput">Hover over this label:</label>
  <input id="myInput" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: This also disables the transfer of focus from the label to the input on click.